# Pass Session Variable From One Form to Another With Link

Tags: php, session-variables

I would whether someone can help me please.

I have the following test form ('form.html'), which if I use a 'Submit Button' I can pass the 'username' and 'locationid' variables to the next form, in this case 'gallery.php'

```
 <form method="post" action="gallery.php"><br/><br/>

 <input type="text" name="username" value="IRHM73" /><br/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="locationid" value="1" /><br/><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit"/><br/><br/>

 </form>
```

and this is the 'gallery.php'

```
<?php 

$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['locationid']=$_POST['locationid'];

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<?php 

  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/';

  $thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
?>
<head> 
  <title>Gallery</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <link href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!--[if IE]>   
  <link href="Styles/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(function() { $('a.fancybox').fancybox(); }); 

  </script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
-->
  </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -476px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "imagefolders.php" /> View Uploaded Images In Folder Structure <a/> &larr; View All Uploaded Images </div>
  <form id="gallery" class="page"> 
  <div id="container"> 
    <div id="center"> 
      <div class="aB"> 
        <div class="aB-B"> 
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <div class="demo"> 
          <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="IRHM73" />
          <input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid" value="1" />
            <div class="inner"> 
              <div class="container"> 
                <div class="gallery"> 
                  <ul class="gallery-image-list"> 
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) : 
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i); 
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $folder = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('folder'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source')); 
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail')); 
                  ?>
                    <li class="item"> 
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview" 
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a></li>
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'));?> <br />
                          <b>Contained in folder:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('folder'));?> </span><br />  
                          <?php endfor; ?>
                          </li>
                        </p>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
        <div class="aB-a">        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm now trying to perform the same action but this time via a link rather than a button.

I've not changed my 'gallery.php script, but my revised form is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['username']="username";
$_SESSION['locationid']="locationid";
echo '<a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>';

?>

 <input type="text" name="username" value="IRHM73" /><br/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="locationid" value="1" /><br/><br/>

 </form>
```

However when I load the form I receive the following error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/form.php:2) in
>   /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/form.php on line 3

I'm not too familiar with 'Session variables' as I'm only just learning. But I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: duplicate of 100000500000 questions on [Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938777/headers-already-sent) error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following:

```
session_start();
```

at the top of gallery.php, not form.html. Also, You cannot submit a form that way unless you use javascript to submit the form upon click of a link, see here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml. Also, you have no opening < form> tag on your form.

Answer (score 1):

session_start() should be called before any output to the browser, so put it before anything is sent. The output is sent from the form.php file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like somewhere in your php pages you have the session_start(); call after other operations (like print hmtl).

Put always session_start() as the first instruction in php pages